# How to show alert when the app is being closed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my app is running in foreground, If user clicks on home button i want to show some alert like

Do u want to  exit the app with Yes/No buttons. Is there any delegate methods called when home button is clicked…

Thank you….

Comment: No, you can't do that in iOS. There is a delegate to notify that but your app will go to background immediately.

Comment: And you are absolutely not supposed to do it anyway. If the user clicks on the home button, they WANT to leave your app. None of your business why, and you have no right to interfere with the user's action. Unless you want 1 star reviews (assuming 0 stars is impossible).

Comment: Please take a minute to accept an answer (by clicking the check mark).  You can also up vote answers, as several people are trying to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this on iOS. I think you want a similar behavior to Android back button.

Think of iOS home button as Android home button, which doesn't let you prompt user either.

Comment: Yeah, i want similar behaviour like android, I too searched on it didn't found  any info, Thanks  for the confirmation..

Answer (score 1):

You can not stop the app to go to background, even if you show the alert message, it will go to the background anyways when you hit the home button and you won't see the alert message either.

There is no delegate method that would trigger when the app is going to the background, but there is a delegate method that will trigger when your app has totally gone to background.

Just to show you visually-

In the AppDelegate implementation file(.m), I added an alert message at the end of `applicationDidEnterBackground` method and put a break point just to check if it is entering that block as I expected. See the result--

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use these methods in **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Comment: This won't help to show the message. applicationDidEnterBackground method will be triggered after the app has totally gone to background not when the home button is clicked.

Comment: what do u suggest then

Comment: I already provided a suggestion. The thing is, in iOS you can't control anything when the user hits on the home button. The app will go to background anyway. We can't halt the process. At least, I didn't find any work around for this scenario.

Comment: You do use applicationDidEnterBackground so whats the difference

Comment: I hope you have got some better reason for giving negative marking. and i want to know that reason

Comment: No, I specifically said- "it will go to the background anyways when you hit the home button and you won't see the alert message either." By the screen shot, I showed the author that the only available method that would catch the trigger is applicationDidEnterBackground but adding an alert message there won't help him because by the time, the method would trigger, the app will already be in the background and then there is no way to show the alert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88360/discussion-between-natasha-and-nischal-hada).

Comment: sounds great.. my answer lack explanation then and wasnt the solution for question